# nested divs positioning with css

Tags: css, css-float

I want to keep my container div text align centered regardless size of the div inside of it.

```
<div id="container">
     I want to stay at the center
     <div id="right-content">Right div effects centered content
     </div>
</div>

#container {
    text-align:center;
        background-color: #888;
        border-radius: 5px;
        -moz-border-radius: 5px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 5px; 
        min-width: 500px;
        height: 65px;
        margin-top: 60px;
}

#right-content {
background-color:#F00;
display:block;
vertical-align:middle;
float:right;
height: 65px;
color:#FFF;
```

}

sorry, right-content attached.

[http://jsfiddle.net/YMsR4/12/](http://jsfiddle.net/YMsR4/13/)

---

No not vertically, actually what i want to do is like the code below but this is not effective to arrange margins with static values.there should be easier way for this.

```
#container {
text-align:center;
background-color: #888;

border-radius: 5px;
-moz-border-radius: 5px;
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;

width: 750px;
height: 65px;
margin-top: 60px;
```

}

```
#right-content {
background-color:#F00;
float:right;
height: 65px;
color:#FFF; 
position: absolute;
margin-top: -20px;
margin-left: 535px;
```

}

DIVs are same.

http://jsfiddle.net/YMsR4/13/

Comment: It's already centered. Do you mean vertically centered?

Comment: Did you forget to include the `#right-content` css?

Answer (score 0):

Make the position of the right-content absolute. That way the removes it from normal flow and it doesn't affect the other div.

Comment: You will have to use `margin:auto` with it if you want it to work